# XLS Report in ODOO 11

Tags: python, odoo

ImportError: No module named 'report_sxw', I need to develope a module that prints xls report but i am facing issues kindly help me solve it, whether odoo11 has the feature of xls or any alternative approach is there to develope a xls report in version 11.

Answer (score 1):

For Odoo 11 download updated module from here.

https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/11.0/report_xlsx

Answer (score 0):

- **TRY BELOW CODE**
- Python code:-

```
from odoo import models
class PartnerXlsx(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.report_xlsx.partner_xlsx'
    _inherit = 'report.report_xlsx.abstract'

def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
    for obj in partners:
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Report')
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        sheet.write(0, 0, obj.name, bold)
```

- XML code:-
  `<report
  id="partner_xlsx"
  model="res.partner"
  string="Print to XLSX"
  report_type="xlsx"
  name="report_xlsx.partner_xlsx"
  file="res_partner"
  attachment_use="False"
  />`

Answer (score 0):

In odoo11 for printing xls report you need to import some libraries because creating this type of file now some methods are change. Likewise

```
 try:
    import xlwt
    from xlwt import Borders
except ImportError:
xlwt = None
```

After this you can create workbook by this way: `workbook = xlwt.Workbook()`

Then you can do your operations here.